# How to transfer a (Mutable)Map to an Data Transfer Object Class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, dictionary, kotlin, dto

I have a Firebase project which contains a Firestore collection of tasks that have an associated:

- taskNumber(**set as the document ID**)
- site(name)
- status
- location(**optional**)
- description(**optional**)
- notes(**optional**)
- long(**optional**)
- lat(**optional**)

There are additional fields  in the Firestore that I do not wish to pass into the data transfer object like `long` and `lat`

Here is an example of the Firebase Firestore data structure:
[image]

I use a snapshot listener to listen for changes made to the database then add the desired docments to an arrayList which I then display in a recycler view

**When I try to run the code below I get Type Mismatch error @ TaskDTO(taskObj)
How do I allow the TaskDTO class to accept a Map?**

Here is the code:

```
val collRef = db.collection("centa_tasks").orderBy("scheduled_date")
        collRef.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->

            if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                ...
            }

            ...

            for ((index,doc) in querySnapshot!!.withIndex()) {

                //Get the main values:
                var taskObj = doc.data

                //Add the task_number:
                taskObj["task_number"] = doc.id

                //Here I compare the current date to the previous date to determine if day item needs 
                //to be shown:
                if(index != 0) {
                    val ts1: Timestamp = querySnapshot.documents[index - 1]["scheduled_date"] as Timestamp
                    val ts2: Timestamp = taskObj["scheduled_date"] as Timestamp

                    taskObj["showDate"] = ts1 != ts2
                }else{
                    taskObj["showDate"] = true
                }
                val task = TaskDTO(taskObj) //This is the line of code that needs to be changed. 
                allTasks.add(task) //I add the task to an arrayList that is sent to recycler adapter. 
            }
```

Here is the data transfer object that contains optional parameters:
**TaskDTO.kt:**

```
data class TaskDTO(var site : String,
                   var taskNumber : String,
                   var status: Int,
                   var showDate : Boolean,
                   var scheduled_date : Timestamp = Timestamp(Date(-1)), //optional
                   var description : Int = 1, //optional
                   var location : String = "No location set!", //optional
                   var notes : String = "" //optional
                  ) {

}
```

**When I try to run the code above I get Type Mismatch error @ TaskDTO(taskObj)
How do I allow the TaskDTO class to accept a Map?**

Comment: I don't understand the nature of your questions.  Are you running into a specific problem that requires additional code?

Comment: My mistake, I should have made that clear. How do I put the MutableMap to the TaskDTO? With the code above I get a Type Mismatch error @ TaskDTO(taskObj)

Comment: I suggest editing the question to make yourself perfectly clear.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to initialize `TaskDTO` with MutableMap, but your `TaskDTO` class has no constructor for that case. You should create new class (I use singleton for that case), for instance `TaskMapper` with method `fun mapTaskDTO(map: MutableMap)` which creates and returns an instance of `TaskDTO` class based on values in instance of MutableMap.
**Note!** This code should not be used as it is. This is just an example, which should show you the way to solve your problem.

```
object TaskMapper{
    fun mapTaskDTO(map: MutableMap<String, String>): TaskDTO{
        return TaskDTO(map["site"]!!,
            map["taskNumber"]!!,
            map["status"]!!.toInt(),
            map["showDate"]!!.toBoolean())
    }
}
```

And then use it like here

```
val task = TaskMapper.mapTaskDTO(taskObj)
```